# setting up android environment in linux ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: android, installation, adt, android-sdk-tools, eclipse-luna

I recently started setting up android environment on my ubuntu (12.04) machine.
First, I installed eclipse luna. After that, I installed ADT plugin from my eclipse Help -> Install New Software and the url - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4.

After plugin installation, I downloaded android sdk from the official site - http://developer.android.com, following the instructions.

Finally, after the installation, I tried creating new project as well as importing other projects, but its giving me R error everytime, as R.java is never getting generated.

Can anyone please help me to understand the problem, as well as finding its solution.

I also got another adt plugin url, i.e, http://developer.android.com,  from official android dev website, so, is that the issue?

What may be the issue - Android SDK or ADT plugin?

Thanks...

Comment: Guys, please, let me know the solution, instead of down-voting it.

Comment: Dont worry about that :) i think the easiest way (if u have decent internet speed) is downloading ADT Bundle for ubuntu. You dont have to setting anything, just use it.

Comment: Any specific reason you're using Eclipse instead of Android Studio? Android Studio is literally download [sdk](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i), unpack in /home/user folder, then download [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download), unpack wherever and start it up from the bin folder. It asks where your SDK is located, point to it and get started.

Comment: I tried using android studio, just before this, but it always just stucks very long, while creating or importing a project, on fetching gradle info, that is really irritating.

Comment: Strange, usually takes about 3 seconds for me on my almost 4 year old laptop with a mechanical disk that has taken a serious beating. Isn't ubuntu 12.04 really old? I'm using a somewhat cleaned up version of Mint myself.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get

```
R cannot be resolved
```

then check for the /res directory and there must be some file that have some error in it and that is preventing the application from being built. For example, it may be a layout file or it may be due to some missing resource is, but you already defined it in the XML file.

If you have any additional, even unused (!) or unreferenced (!) images in a folder like res/drawables-mdpi which do not comply to the file naming conventions (may contain only [a-z0-9_.]), the R.java class might not generate, causing the chain of events all the other posts referred to. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, Tardo, but as I mentioned in my post. That error is even in new projects being created. SO, I don't think new project's resource folder will have error, without mentioning in console. One more thing, I just installed sdk and adt plugin. So, I guess the error is in one of them.

Comment: I had the same issue a few days ago. Go into your Project -> Properties -> Android. Check if your Project Build Target is selected.

Comment: Yup, that is selected.

Comment: What about Project -> Clean ? If it still doesn't works, please put your log error.

Comment: Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ADK Build-tools. Build fails silently if they don't match.

Comment: Okay, need to check this.